# Listing all files in dir

Tags: bash

I have a bash script where I need to loop over all files in a folder.

This is my currently function to tothat:

```
function listDir(){

   for file in "$1"/*;
   do 
      echo $file
   done 
}
```

The problem is that it's not listing hidden files or folder (.hiddenFile). How can I achieve that?

Acording to Kusalananda answer, I've edited my script to looks like:

```
listDir () {
    for file in $(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print);
    do
       echo $file
    done
}
```

However, this is not working with folders with spaces in name. Note that I need the for loop to do other stuff with that file names, not just listing them.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Kusalananda's answer didn't include a for loop with an echo.  Just run `find` as he suggested without a loop.

Comment: If using `find`, don't loop.  If you need to loop, use then loop "within `find`" using `-exec` as I just showed below.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` shell globbing pattern does not by default match hidden names.

In `bash`, you may make it do that by enabling the `dotglob` shell option.  You do this with `shopt -s dotglob`.

Note that you also would have to quote the expansion of `$file` in your code, or the shell would perform word splitting and filename globbing on its value.

```
listDir () (
    shopt -s dotglob
    for pathname in "$1"/*; do
        printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
    done
)
```

If you need to do other things with `$pathname` in the loop above, make sure to double quote the expansion of the variable as `"$pathname"`.  This would make the function work for filenames that contain all manner of characters.

When calling the function, make sure to quote the directory name if it contains spaces:

```
listDir "my directory/here somewhere"
```

---

Two alternative approaches (assuming that you just need to list the files):

```
listDir () (
    shopt -s dotglob
    printf '%s\n' "${1:-.}"/*
)
```

By enclosing the function body in `( ... )` (a subshell), we ensure that he `dotglob` shell option is not set in the calling shell.

By using `${1:-.}` in place of just `$1`, we use `.` (the current directory) as the default directory to list if no directory (or an empty string) is given.

The `printf` utility will reuse its format string if given more arguments than there are placeholders in the formatting string.  Here, we use that fact to print out the filenames as a newline-delimited list.

Using `find`, which does not need `dotglob`:

```
listDir () {
    find "${1:-.}" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print
}
```

---

If you want to do something else with the found files when you are using `find`, then *don't* try to loop over the output of `find`.  Instead, use `-exec`:

```
listDir () {
    find "${1:-.}" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec sh -c '
        for pathname do
            # code that does something with "$pathname"
        done' sh {} +
}
```

Related:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)
- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you suggest is working fine with hidden files, but, what happens with folder names with spaces? That's why I had "$1" with quotes in my original script, how can I solve this with your answer?

Comment: @SwDev Quoting `$1` is the right thing to do. This makes your code work on folders with spaces.  Note that you would have to quote the folder name on the command line, e.g., `listDir "my folder"`.  Without the quotes when calling `listDir`, `$1` would only get the value `my` in this example.

Comment: @SwDev See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged bash, you could also use arrays:

```
shopt -s dotglob
files=( "$1"/* )
```

Then you can print them or operate on them:

```
printf "File: %s\n" "${files[@]}"
```

or

```
rm "${files[@]}"
```

or

```
for f in "${files[@]}"; do mv "${f}" "renamed-${f}"; done
```